# Spectrum computation of a specific linear operator on a Banach space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, spectral-theory

Apology in advance for the long question.

I have this family of operators parametrized by a real $k$:
$$
{{\mathcal{L}}} v=\left((1-e^{-|x|})v\right)'-k\,{\rm{sgn}}(x)e^{-|x|}v
$$
on the space $C_b(\mathbb{R})$ of continuous bounded functions on the whole line. On $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, it would make the analysis slightly different but the same question would arise.
The solution of
$$
{{\mathcal{L}}} v-\lambda v=0
$$
for $x<0$ is
$$
v_{H-}=e^{\lambda x}(e^x-1)^{k-1-\lambda},
$$
and for $x>0$
$$
v_{H+}=e^{\lambda x}(1-e^{-x})^{k-1+\lambda}.
$$
We restrict ourselves to $\lambda>0$ real for simplicity. For $k>1$, $v_{H-}$ is bounded and continuous if $0<\lambda< k-1$ and we have the eigenfunction
$$
v=
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
v_{H-},&x<0\\
\displaystyle{0},&x>0.
\end{array}\right.
$$
The resolvent equation
$$
{{\mathcal{L}}} v-\lambda v=f
$$
for $x<0$ is solved by
$$
v_{-}=e^{\lambda x}(e^x-1)^{k-1-\lambda}\int_0^x \frac{f(x')e^{-\lambda x'}}{(e^{x'}-1)^{k-\lambda}}dx',
$$
and for $x>0$ by
$$
v_{+}=e^{\lambda x}(1-e^{-x})^{k-1+\lambda}\int_\infty^x \frac{f(x')e^{-\lambda x'}}{(1-e^{-x'})^{\lambda+k}}dx'.
$$
Still in the case $k>1$ but here for $\lambda>k-1$, the equation
$$
v=
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
v_{-},&x<0\\
\displaystyle{v_+},&x>0.
\end{array}\right.
$$
defines a solution to the resolvent equation in $C_b(\mathbb{R})$. Thus in the case $k>1$, the spectrum on the real positive real line is $0< \lambda\leq k-1$, almost all point spectrum.

If $k<1$ (remember we consider $\lambda>0$ real), $v_{H-}$ is not bounded at the origin and  $v_{H+}$ is not bounded at $+\infty$. Thus there is no point spectrum. However, for $\lambda<1-k$, $v_+$ above, while bounded at $+\infty$, is not bounded at $0$ and there is no way to fix that by changing the limits of integration. If you change $\infty$ to $0$ in the integral for example, then $v_+$ is not bounded at $+\infty$. So I have this region of the spectrum $0<\lambda<1-k$ that I don't really understand. Is this just essential spectrum? It just does not "look" as I would expect for essential spectrum. Or maybe I made a mistake in my reasoning. Admittedly, my question is a bit vague. Any insight would be appreciated.